# iOS: App crashes when pressing record in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Regardless of the template I pick in Instruments (Allocations, Leaks, Activity Monitor) - the app crashes right away when pressing record. There is NO stack trace or any warning whatsoever - and after that the Instruments sometimes freezes and needs to be forcibly shut down.

I'm using XCode 6.3.2.

I should also add that this is happening on my device.

Comment: Try by enabling Zombie possibly deallocated object.

Comment: I did that, still crashing on me

Answer (score 11):

I found a workaround.
After installing app to phone via XCode, I kill the app.
Then I go to Instruments and select the app in Instruments and press the record.
This launches the app on the phone and the Instruments work!

Also, the proper way to launch Instruments is by pressing CMD-I in XCode. I was opening it from the developer tools which is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since in my scenario it's a provider service that I'm trying to profile. The provider crashes the moment i click "record" in instruments, so there is no way to launch it from xcode...

Comment: +1 It was crashing on me when attaching to an existing process. Allowing Instruments to launch the app fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you got to 'Window -> Devices and Simulators' you can look at the crash logs on the device in question.